# How to display the text left and right side at the bottom if div is the center of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am displaying the box with text in the center of the screen which is working. Now I am adding the footer at the bottom but that is displaying at the top because my div is absolute. I have to display at the bottom with the left and right text.

```css
  .bg_cyan{background-color: #5AFCEB;}
  .center_screen{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
  .thankyou_set{top: 50%;}
  .thankyou_set .thanku_popup3{
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 50px;
   background-color: red;
  }
  .thankyou_content h2{font-size: 30px;}

  .form_terms{
   margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style: none;
   float: right;
  }
  .form_terms li{display: inline-block;margin: 10px;}
  .form_terms li a{color: #5e5e5e;font-size: 18px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="clearfix">

  <div class="thankyou_set center_screen">
   <div class="thanku_popup3">
    <div class="thankyou_content">
     <h2>Thank you for registering!</h2>
     
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>


  </div>
  <div class="corp_footer">
   <div class="form_copy_right pull-left">
   <p>&#169; All right reserved</p>
  </div>
   <ul class="form_terms">
    <li><a href="website">Website</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>


 </div>
```

I am getting the output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to absolute position when we have [the power of **Flexbox**](https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/dKxXRP) these days. [Here's a CodePen you can play around with](https://codepen.io/codespent/pen/dKxXRP) to see how other elements will behave, but vertical alignment is easy with Flexbox by setting the parent container to `display:flex;` then give the child element (what you want centered) a margin of `margin: auto auto;` to perfectly center it to the center of its parent **both vertically and horizontally**.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.thankyou_content {
  margin: auto auto;
}

.thankyou_set .thanku_popup3 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}

.thankyou_content h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.corp_footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form_terms {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

.form_terms li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.form_terms li a {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thankyou_content">
    <h2>Thank you for registering!</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="corp_footer">
  <div class="form_copy_right pull-left">
    <p>&#169; All right reserved</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="form_terms">
    <li><a href="website">Website</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have to display the " Thank you for registering!" in the center of the screen.

Comment: Well are all of those containers necessary for something else? If not just have a single container, but nesting your content within 4-5 containers that have random styles makes it pretty difficult to work with..

Comment: I added my output.

Comment: This does not help. Where did you get this code? Did you write it or copy it from somewhere? Where are all these divs from and what are they needed for?

By eliminating those, assuming they're not needed, you can create one flex container that'll center your banner where you want it.

Comment: Updated my answer to show you generally how I'd approach this, but its up to you to determine structure and apply to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You do this very easily with write some flex properties. All you have to do now just replace the below code and you get the result.

```css
.main-container{
  height:100vh;
}

.content{
  display:flex;
  background:red;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff;
}

.corp_footer{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.thankyou_content h2{
  font-size:30px;
}

.thankyou_content{
   width: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 50px;
   background-color: red;
   text-align:center;
}

.center_screen{
flex:3;
align-items:center;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

.form_terms{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 
  
}
.form_terms li a{
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.form_terms li a{
  color: #5e5e5e;font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container main-container">
  <div class="content">
      <div class="thankyou_set center_screen">
   <div class="thanku_popup3">
    <div class="thankyou_content">
     <h2>Thank you for registering!</h2>
     
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
      
       <div class="corp_footer">
   <div class="form_copy_right pull-left">
   <p>&#169; All right reserved</p>
  </div>
   <ul class="form_terms">
    <li><a href="website">Website</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  

 </div>
```

Comment: Any other solution without flex?

Comment: It is the easiest solution than others. because when you use positioning element you can't control the responsiveness without writing media query. but using flex you can control responsiveness without writing media query.